# Can't dynamically redirect to last visited page with django social auth

Tags: django, django-socialauth

When on a specific event page.  The user can login using django social auth, but will redirect them to a static url, with the option below

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/dashboard/'
```

I was wondering if there is a dynamic way of redirecting to the page where they logged in.  I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
{% url socialauth_begin 'facebook' %}?redirect_uri={{ request.get_full_path }}
```

Any suggestions would be great thanks.

Matthew

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [source code](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/social_auth/views.py#L105) all you need is to set `?next=`.

Like `{% url socialauth_begin 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.get_full_path }}` or another field name if setted `REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME`

Comment: Its always so obvious.  Awesome, Thanks!!